# 404 Error using compose for Google Cloud Storage in Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have several files I want to upload to Google Cloud Storage and then combine using `compose`. I am able to upload the files but cannot get compose to work. I originally tried it with Nodejs and got weird errors and now tried to use compose in a cloud function written in python. Here is the code I am using:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def compose_file(event, context):
    bucket_name = 'bucket-name-appspot.com'
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    blob1 = bucket.blob('composettest/compose1.txt')
    blob2 = bucket.blob('composettest/compose2.txt')

    sources = [blob1, blob2]
    destination_blob_name = 'compose3.txt'
    print(blob1)
    print(blob2)

    destination = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    print(destination)
    destination.content_type = "text/plain"
    destination.compose(sources)
    return destination
```

And this is the error I keep getting. I know the file exists because I can print it as a blob. Any ideas? Is there possibly some sort of permission error? I doubt it's that because I can create and download files no problem. I just can't get compose to work with either python or the nodejs client libraries.

```
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 449, in run_background_function
    _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 268, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 265, in call_user_function
    event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context))
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 26, in compose_file
    destination.compose(sources)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 3070, in compose
    retry=retry,
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_http.py", line 63, in api_request
    return call()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 438, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket-name-appspot.com/o/compose3.txt/compose?prettyPrint=false: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compose in a new file. You take a file and you compose it with another one. In your case, either you first create a compose3.txt empty in GCS and then you can create your command. Or, you use the compose1 as destination and only the compose2 as source, and both are composed together.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're specifying a non-existent bucket:

```
% gsutil ls gs://bucket-name-appspot.com
BucketNotFoundException: 404 gs://bucket-name-appspot.com bucket does not exist.
```

Comment: The bucket does exist. I just changed the name for posting this code. I can grab files in the bucket no problem. Just can't compose them.